# C prog figuring out where the bug is

Tags: c

guys help i'm having a problem in getting all the product of odd nums, whenever i enter 1, 3, 2, 2, the product of all odd nums is 0, it's not executing 1*3 =3... can you please point it out why, Thanks in advance...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{  
int arr[2][2], r, c, sum=0, prod, sumD=0, count=0, count2=0, sumAveEven;

for (r=0; r < 2; r++)
{


    for (c=0; c < 2; c++)
    {
        printf("Enter  Numbers: ");
        scanf("%d", &arr[r][c]);  


        if(r==c)
        {
           sumD = sumD + arr[r][c];  //sum of diagonal pattern

        }   
        if(arr[r][c]%2==0)
        {
          sum = sum + arr[r][c]; //sum ofeven nums  
          count= count +1; 
          sumAveEven = sum / count; 

        }
        else //(arr[r][c]%2 !=0)
        {
           prod = prod * arr[r][c]; //prod of odd nums

        }

        //printf("%d ", arr[r][c]);
    }
   // printf("%d\n", sum);
}
printf("The Sum of All Even Numbers is:  %d \n", sum);
printf("The AVERAGE of All Even Numbers is:  %d \n", sumAveEven);
printf("The product of All Odd Numbers is: %d \n", prod);
printf("The Sum of Elements in pattern Diagonal is: %d \n", sumD);
//printf("Counter: %d \n", count);    
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this shouldn't be tagged [java] btw

Comment: Just initialize `prod` to be 1

Comment: But the thing is if the prod is 1, then if i did not enter any Odd Number then it will still print out sum of odd is 1... i guess it needs more complex programming... Thanks Everyone. Kudos!

Comment: ... Don't remove the question content.

Comment: Rolled the question back. Don't edit out your question, it doesn't help any future visitor.

Comment: Don't you agree that Java and C have the same Logic?

Comment: As a warning, do not delete your question body again. If you do so, I will need to take more serious action here.

Answer (score 6):

`prod` is not initialized. You need to initialize it to `1`

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the only problem but `prod` is never initialised so

```
prod = prod * arr[r][c];
```

will always give unpredictable results.  As noted in other answers, you should initialise it to 1 when it is declared.

```
int ... sum=0, prod=1, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not initializing `prod`, which means it could be anything. It was PROBABLY zero in your run, and since anything times zero is zero, that's what you were getting.

In actuality, `prod = prod * arr[r][c];` is returning something unknown.

It looks like you probably want to initialize `prod` to 1 so you have a starting point when calculating your product.

Answer (score 1):

You're not initializing `prod`.  initialize it to `1`

```
int arr[2][2], r, c, sum=0, prod=1, sumD=0, count=0, count2=0, sumAveEven;
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialize `prod`. Most of the time it will be set to `0`...